# The api server cannot create the file when receives a put request

Tags: rest, api, file, put

I am new in APIs. I have a java api server. In put method on server side, i receive a string and i create a arff file using that string. then i do some process on that file and return the result which is another string.
The problem is that when i do a put request the file is not created in local path, but when i run the code on a local application for test the file is created so the code works.
I have to generate a file of that string because i am using a machine learning algorithm that only works with files.Does anyone know why is that?

the method Classify text is called in put method in server side

```
public static int ClassifyText(String trained_model, String text) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {

    String evaluation_file = "..\toBeClassified_text.arff";

    //create a arff file for the text
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(evaluation_file));
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
```

Comment: To begin with, when you're running a local application then `..` is the parent directory of the current directory (where you're running the application) but when running in an application server, you don't know what the current directory is, so don't know where `..` is either. More information about your server environment (what web server and/or application server?) would be helpful. Also, `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter` looks like it's _probably_ Java, but you should tell us what language you're using. By the way, if it's Java you should use `../` not `..\\` (use forward, not backslashes)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. Yes the server is Java and the client is a html page using ajax to make the call to the server. I use Netbeans.

Comment: The question is that how can I give server access to a file.Where should I save files to enable server access them.

Comment: Btw I use goldfish in Netbeans as webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by modifiying thisline:

String evaluation_file = "D:\toBeClassified_text.arff";